# FME values used in python

Tags: python, fme-form, python-2.6

I need one attribute value from FME and use it in python script as a parameter. How can I do this? Do I have to have def_*init*_() def input(), def close() also?

Comment: http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Python-and-FME-Basics

Answer (score 6):

To view the API documentation, navigate to your FME installation folder and go to this location: help\python\apidoc\index.html

In this case you'll want to use the GetAttribute method:

> **getAttribute(attrName)**
>
> Get the value of the named attribute.  A return of None indicates the
>   attribute does not exist.
>
> Parameters:
>           attrName (string) - The name of the attribute to get.
>
> Returns: bool, int, long, float, string, list of string, or None
>       The value of the named attribute.